# A way to copy names of nginx modules used, from an already installed remote server

Tags: nginx, homebrew

I'm trying to replicate `nginx` installation of modules from a pre configured environment on `AWS`. Basically I want to get all the additional modules installed along with nginx on a remote server, and replicate that on my local machine. I dont know what is installed on the remote server, but I can do

```
nginx -V
```

But it's a laundry list and considering that installing 3rd party modules additionally requires reinstallation of the whole module, is there a way to quickly get a dump of all modules from the remote installation and add it? 
So far I have done

```
brew tap homebrew/nginx

brew install nginx-full
```

But I want to know what all modules are installed on the server, so I can add them to the above command. For instance for `upload-module`

```
 brew install nginx-full --with-upload-module
```

Or Is there a way to install all available 3rd party modules. (Which I dont think is very efficient)

Comment: Just share the Nginx -V output and let us see the other 3rd party modules, there are usually either popular and easy to install of rare and useless.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did like mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/a/472513/169464)

```
 2>&1 nginx -V | xargs -n1
```

And got(relevant portions only)

```
--with-debug
--with-pcre-jit
--with-ipv6
--with-http_ssl_module
--with-http_stub_status_module
--with-http_realip_module
--with-http_auth_request_module
--with-http_addition_module
--with-http_dav_module
--with-http_geoip_module
--with-http_gunzip_module
--with-http_gzip_static_module
--with-http_image_filter_module
--with-http_spdy_module
--with-http_sub_module
--with-http_xslt_module
--with-mail
--with-mail_ssl_module
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.8.0/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.8.0/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.8.0/debian/modules/nginx-echo
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.8.0/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.8.0/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Guess its a nice hack to have handy, here on SO